# ssh remote file execution is not working

Tags: ssh, sshpass

I have a bash script `test.sh` that contains the following commands

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSWORD=""
USERNAME=""
REM_HOSTNAME='localhost'

FILES_TO_COPY="remote_exec.sh"


function scptmp {
    exec sshpass -p $PASSWORD scp -o "ConnectTimeout 3" \
        -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" \
        -o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" \
        "$@"
}

echo -e "\tCopying files to remote host..."
scptmp -r -q $FILES_TO_COPY $USERNAME@$REM_HOSTNAME:/tmp

echo -e "\tSet execution privs on remote file..."
sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $USERNAME@$REM_HOSTNAME "echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S chmod +x /tmp/$FILES_TO_COPY"

echo -e "\Execute..."
sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -t $USERNAME@$REM_HOSTNAME "echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S bash /tmp/$FILES_TO_COPY"
```

And the `remote_exec.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname=`hostname`
mkdir $hostname
```

When I execute the script with

```
bash test.sh
```

I don't receive any error, but the `remote_exec.sh` doesn't seem to be executed on the host since no directory is created.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: What you get if you run `set -x` before running the script? Do you have the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on the first line of your script?

Comment: Before running which script? The `test.sh`?

Comment: I run the `set -x` now in the terminal before executing `bash test.sh` but it just returns `+ bash linux_pentest.sh`

Comment: Try to put it into the script on the line before the `sshpass`.

Comment: I did but no difference!?

Comment: Instead of posting bits and pieces, why don't you show the whole file? Just get rid of sensitive stuff (password, user, host) - that way we can try it out instead of having to guess.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't think that would be necessary, I updated the original post now with a working example (just fill in the username and password)

Comment: Maybe just add the output of `bash -x test.sh` (with sensitive information redacted).

Answer (score 1):

With `exec`, you replace the current shell with the process resulting from executing the following command.  This means that when you call your `scptmp` function, the shell that is currently executing your script is replaced by the `sshpass` process.  When the `sshpass` utility in the function has finished executing, the script will no longer be running.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes inhibit evaluation of variables inside them. Try double quotes:

```
sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -t user@host "echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S bash /tmp/remote_exec.sh"
```

Comment: I changed it to double quotes but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Does it work if you just type the above command line in, replacing both instances of $PASSWORD by the actual password (as well as the user and host placeholders)? If not, then something else is wrong. If yes, I'm not sure why the above would not work.

Comment: Yes it works when I execute it in a terminal! I have now double checked everything and found a possible problem (Updated the initial post)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was connecting to the remote for the first time with the user executing the script.
Hence, try to

```
SSH <REMOTE_IP>
```

with the affected user. If there's a prompt about "authenticity of host ", then this might be issue.

```
The authenticity of host '<REMOTE-IP>' can't be established.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Depending on the environment and your policies, you may just confirm and re-launch the script.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -t user@host<<EOF
echo uname -a
cd /tmp/ || exit 1
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S bash ./remote_exec.sh
exit $?

EOF
```

Comment: I have tried the above code but I receive the following error `test.sh: line 47: warning: here-document at line 34 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
test.sh: line 48: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: removed the space before the <<EOF but should be working just tested with passwordless connectivity

Comment: Yeah I fixed then already when I tried it, but nevertheless didn't work